# Devices in Device Specific image set in asset catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, asset-catalog

I want to update my app for the new iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. To do so I selected an image set from my asset catalog in Xcode 6. As I develop only for iPhone I selected "Device Specific" in the Xcode Attribute Inspector. Now I can chose between the following devices:

- iPhone
- Retina 4-inch
- iPad
- Mac

Selecting only **iPhone** I get these sizes:

- 1x
- 2x
- 3x

Selecting only **Retina 4-inch** gives me only one size:

- Retina 4 2x

Why is the 4-inch screen different from 3.5, 4.7 and 5.5 inches? It would make sense in my view to combine *1x* and *2x* as they are both available on devices with a 4:3 aspect ratio and *Retina 4 2x* and *3x* for devices with a 16:9 aspect ratio.

My real question: What do I need to provide in order to support iOS 7.0 and later? I obviously don't need a *1x* image as my app does not support any non-retina devices. *2x* seems reasonable for the iPhone 4s. Do I need *Retina 4 2x* if I provide *2x* already? Will the iPhone 6 use the *2x* or the *Retina 2x*? *3x* is for the iPhone 6 Plus, no question about that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1x: no need
- 2x: 3.5', 4' and 4.7' — see below for 4'
- 3x: 5.5'
- Retina 4 2x: 4' if image ratio is different from 3.5', i.e. image have the same width but different height

Comment: Any idea why is the iPhone 6 using the 2x images, which are with different aspect ration (4:3 compared to the 16:9 for the iPhone 6), instead of the Retina 4 ones which are with 16:9?

Comment: I guess this page can answer your question: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: Why there is no need for 1x?
How do we design it in xib without 1x images?

Comment: There is no need for 1x because only retina iPhones are able to run iOS 7

Comment: you forgot the iPad 2. Yes, you need 1x for iOS 7.

Comment: That's right, iPad 2 or iPad mini for example need 1x. I did not mention them because I thought of iPhone only.